# Biasing a transistor with a Zener diode (calculate R)

Tags: resistors, bjt, zener, bias

I am trying to have a stable output voltage (12V) for the power supply that is changing between 28 V- 150V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH9JoV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I checked the datasheet of the Zener [DDZ9699S](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30409.pdf) and I simply designed based on the current mentioned:
[image: DDZ9699S datasheet]

```
V1(28V)-12=R1 x 50u
```

It gives me R1= 320 k, but from the result of the simulation I know that I am doing something wrong as the output does not stay around 12V. Could you please help me to find the steps that I have to take to find the resistor value?

I already know that the answer is around 27.4 Kohm.

Comment: 320 K should provide enough current to get the Zener diode to about 12 volts - but you have toreduce R1 to allow for the base current of the transistor which will also flow through R1, increasing its voltage drop.  The base current will depend on the load current and transistor beta.

Comment: Looks like a good recipe for smoke and popping sounds with 138V from collector to base on a 2N3904.

Comment: Look for a 2N2551 or something still better. Also, what's your worst case load current from the BJT emitter?

Comment: @Peter Bennett why should I care about the base current? I believe it is small around pico amper?

Comment: I simulated my design on LTSPICE, and I used a general transistor. At this point, is it really important? I am trying to understand how can I get the 27.4 kohm value

Comment: How do you know that you need 27.4 kilohm? How did you determine that the base current was in the picoampere range?

Comment: @ jonk I do not know what is my worst case load current!

Comment: @ Elliot Alderson I was told about the value without any direction, and the simulation proves that the output would be constant around 11.9 to 12.2 V for changing the power supply from 28 to 150V

Comment: You cannot complete the design without knowing the worst-case load current. Transistor base current (worst-case will likely be when the transistor just meets minimum beta spec *and* is at minimum temperature) and transistor dissipation are both important. You need to add the worst-case base current to the zener current at minimum input voltage and then go back and check that it's still okay at maximum input voltage.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Understood. Thank you

Comment: 2n3904 won't take 150 V.

Comment: @stretch I think Spehro nailed that in comment #2 above. But it is always a good point, just the same.